# How to get a List of cocktails based on the name

Tags: android, sql, kotlin, mvvm, android-room

From my API, I get all the cocktails by name, lets say, if I put margarita in the searchView of my app. It will return all the cocktails that match that query. I save all the queries the user does to let them search for cocktails even when they are offline.

I have created this query that should return a list of cocktails if the name of the cocktail matches the name passed in the searchView

```
@Query("SELECT * 
        FROM cocktailTable 
        WHERE cocktail_name = :cocktailName")
suspend fun getCocktails(cocktailName:String):List<CocktailEntity>
```

But this does not return any cocktails even when the fetch has succefully added those cocktails in my database, any clue ?

I have tried with the IN operator like this

```
@Query("SELECT * 
        FROM cocktailTable 
        WHERE cocktail_name IN (:cocktailName)")
suspend fun getCocktails(cocktailName:String):List<CocktailEntity>
```

But it also does not return all the cocktails with that name

Added code for the call

```
     override suspend fun getCocktailByName(cocktailName: String): Resource<List<Cocktail>>? {
    
            when (val cocktailList = networkDataSource.getCocktailByName(cocktailName)) {
                is Resource.Success -> {
                    for (cocktail in cocktailList.data) {
                        saveCocktail(cocktail.asCocktailEntity())
                    }
                }
                is Resource.Failure -> {
                    return getCocktails(cocktailName)
                }
            }
            return getCocktails(cocktailName)
        }

 override suspend fun getCocktails(cocktailName: String): Resource<List<Cocktail>>? {
        return cocktailDao.getCocktails(cocktailName)
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure the cocktails data are in your database? You can verify it with a "SELECT * from cocktailTable". And are you sure of your table name and your column name?

Comment: yes, I have them populated, I have checked it without this query

Comment: Can you put your code where you're calling `getCocktails`?

Comment: Done @Powkachu edited

Comment: Sorry, I don't find the problem

Comment: try use Like operator and upper. `UPPER(cocktail_name) = UPPER(:cocktailName)`

Comment: not working @ClaudioLopes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `LIKE '%' || :drinkName || '%'` your api might give you whitespaces. You can also try trimming before saving the entity.